# Updating state when database gets updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I got a schema looking something like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Schema
const PhoneNumbersSchema = new Schema({
  phone_numbers: {
    phone_number: 072382838232
    code: ""
    used: false
  },
});

module.exports = PhoneNumbers = mongoose.model(
  "phonenumbers",
  PhoneNumbersSchema
);
```

And then I got an end-point that gets called from a 3rd party application that looks like this:

```
let result = await PhoneNumbers.findOneAndUpdate(
    { country_name: phoneNumberCountry },
    { $set: {"phone_numbers.$[elem1].services.$[elem2].sms_code": 393} },
    { arrayFilters: [ { "elem1.phone_number": simNumberUsed }, { "elem2.service_name": "steam" } ] },
```

Basically the end-point updates the "code" from the phone numbers in the database.

In react this is how I retrieve my phone numbers from the state:

```
const phonenumbers_database = useSelector((state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return state.phonenumbers ? state.phonenumbers.phone_numbers_details : [];
  });
```

Every time the code gets changed in my database from the API call I would like to update "phonenumbers_database" in my state automatically.

How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB can actually watch for changes to a collection or a DB by opening a [Change Stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/changeStream/).

First, you would open up a WebSocket from your React app to the server using something like [Socket.io](https://socket.io), and then [watch for changes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-watch) on your model:

```js
PhoneNumbers
  .watch()
  .on('change', data => socket.emit('phoneNumberUpdated', data));
```

Your third party app will make the changes to the database to your API, and then the changes will be automatically pushed back to the client.

Comment: I managed to make it work. but the "data" I get is a whole object. How do I get only that specific array from that object that got changed?

Comment: Try logging the object to the console to inspect it to see what you need. I can only guess what the server is returning.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67405600/return-specific-array-from-object-collection

Answer (score 0):

You could do a polling and check the Database every N secs or by using [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)

After that, to notify your frontend app, you need to use WebSockets, check on [Socket IO](https://socket.io/)

Comment: I basically want to update "phonenumbers_database" every time the "code" gets changed in the database. I find your way a bit too complicated maybe? But I'll try

Comment: You have 3 different layers, the DB, the backend  and the frontend
For this to happen, your backend code needs to know about the change that is why I suggested the polling or something similar
Them your backend code need to send to the frontend hence WS is your best choise.

What you want to do sounds simple but is not