# Return specific array from object collection

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

So I get some data into my socket
The code in Client is :

```
useEffect(() => {  
    
    const socket = io("http://localhost:5000/api/socket");
    
    socket.on("newThought", (thought) => {
      console.log(thought);
    });
    
  }, []);
```

And then the code in my server is

```
connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connected");

  console.log("Setting change streams");
  const thoughtChangeStream = connection.collection("phonenumbers").watch();

  thoughtChangeStream.on("change", (change) => {
   
    io.of("/api/socket").emit("newThought", change);

  });
});
```

When something in my "phonenumbers" collection gets changed I get in return the whole collection . How would I be able to only get the array that got changed from the object in collection?
[image]
So for example if in the collection the only service that changed is the one with id "607deefd13c4ebcbcfa0900a" that should be the only one returned and not the whole collection object.

Comment: The output doesn't look like the correct format for the data returned from a change event. It should return only the document that was changed. See the last code example output here: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/changeStream/. `change.fullDocument` should contain the document that was changed.

Comment: In my example it contains the document that was changed. But you can see in the image that I have an object and a lot of arrays. I would only like get that specific array that was changed and not the full object.

Comment: Do you have all the phone numbers stored in a single document? Can you post your React code?

Comment: Yes, all the phone numbers are in a single document. And which react code you would like to see?

Comment: If you have all your phone numbers in a single document, that's why you're seeing all of them, so I'm not sure how you can tell which one had been changed. Would it be possible to store them in separate documents?

Comment: I don't think I would be able to store them in separate documents. I hoped there was a way to get only the one that was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fullDocument` parameter to the options (second) argument to the `watch` method can be used to get a delta describing the changes to the document for `update` operations:

```
const thoughtChangeStream = connection.collection("phonenumbers").watch([], {
  fullDocument: 'updateLookup'
});

thoughtChangeStream.on("change", (change) => {
   
  io.of("/api/socket").emit("newThought", change);

});
```

This will then return a response document like this where `updateDescription` contains the fields that were modified by the update:

```
{
  _id: {
    _data: '8260931772000000012B022C0100296E5A1004ABFC09CB5798444C8126B1DBABB9859946645F696400646082EA7F05B619F0D586DA440004'
  },
  operationType: 'update',
  clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1620252530 },
  ns: { db: 'yourDatabase', coll: 'yourCollection' },
  documentKey: { _id: 6082ea7f05b619f0d586da44 },
  updateDescription: {
    updatedFields: { updatedField: 'newValue' },
    removedFields: []
  }
}
```

Note: This will only work for `update` operations and will not work for `replace`, `delete`, `insert`, etc.

**See also:**

- http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html.
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see any delta describing the changes. Where would that be?